# parking in garage with limited front space

Tags: car

I have very limited space in front of my garage to turn the car and the width of the garage is just enough to park-in. Should I try in reverse parking or front parking in such a situation as I don't have much space to turn in front?

Comment: Yes, photo or diagram.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do. A diagram would help. If you're trying to park in a garage and have limited space for turning before you are onto the road I would recommend that you reverse off the road and onto your driveway, into the garage. Doing so is a lot safer than driving in but having to reverse out into the road when you leave the house again. You're already on the road when coming home so you know what other traffic is around, you can pull up on the side of the road and easily see moving traffic then reverse onto your driveway and into the garage when the road is clear. You're also doing your slow manoeuvring on a warm engine rather than a cold one.

If you don't have parking sensors or they don't work well because they detect the side walls of the garage you can carefully park the car one time, perhaps with an assistant helping you, then hang a tennis ball on a string from the ceiling of the garage so that it touches the back windscreen of the car. Now for all future parking attempts you can reverse until you see the screen bump into the ball and you will know you have reached the perfect location for the parking. Keep close to the house wall with the passenger side of the car to give maximum room for you to open your driver door. You can also tell passengers to get out before you reverse into the garage especially if they are kids who would throw the door open and bang it on the wall. If you seat a baby on the driver side of the car then you can easily get the baby out in the garage, which can be helpful if it is raining/baby is sleeping, and it is often better to put babies on the driver side because you are fully in control of getting it out of the car. Putting older kids who can open the door themselves on the passenger side of the car is safer for them because they are next to the sidewalk when you park on a road (generally you should always park so that the passenger side is next to the sidewalk/so your car points in he same direction as the traffic flow). If they are tempted to open their door themselves and jump out they won't be jumping out into the road

Lastly, consider putting some old scraps of carpet on the walls of the garage where the car door edges touch, or where any corners of pillars etc are in the garage. It's easier to remove a dent from a car if the paint is not damaged as it can often be pulled out but scratches caused by banging the car on a sharp brick wall will need to be painted over, which takes longer and costs more